# loop that goes through every item of every array but only for the first array's length

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array of arrays of elements like so:

```
var result = [
// outer array
    [
    // inner first array
        {name: 'A', value: 111},
        {name: 'B', value: 222},
        {name: 'C', value: 333},
        ...
    ],
    [
    // inner subsequent arrays #2
        {name: 'D', value: 55},
        {name: 'E', value: 99},
        ...
    ],
    // inner subsequent arrays #3
        {name: 'F', value: 1000},
        ...
    ],
    ...
    ...
]
```

I want to go through each of the elements (`A-F`) but for each element of only the first array (`A-C`).

Like this:

AA, AB, AC, AD, AE, AF

BB, BC, BD, BE, BF

CC, CD, CE, CF

**EDIT**: I don't know the length of any of the arrays, so I can't use any constants.

Also, it's not just 2 arrays (updated example above).

Comment: It is not a valid JavaScript object.

Comment: Logic Clue: Use foreach inside foreach

Comment: @thefourtheye not an object, but it is a valid javascript array.

Comment: an array is an object too, so you can say it is a valid JS object

Comment: @thefourtheye fixed. it is now

Comment: @Jite If the items contained in an Array is not valid, Array is also not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Reduce all the arrays into a single array
var result = result.reduce(function(result, current) {
    return result.concat(current);
}, []);

// Iterate till the end of the first array
for (var i = 0; i < result[0].length; i += 1) {
    // Start from the current i and iterate till the end
    for(var j = i; j < result.length; j += 1) {
        console.log(result[i].name + result[j].name);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
AA
AB
AC
AD
AE
AF
BB
BC
BD
BE
BF
CC
CD
CE
CF
...
...
```

Comment: @laggingreflex I updated the answer, please check. Do you want all the combinations?

Comment: Pardon if I'm mistaken, but won't this only work if the first array contains exactly half of the total number of array elements? I don't see any stipulation in the question guaranteeing that condition will be true.

Comment: @JLRishe You may be correct, I included only the generic version.

Comment: I don't think your new answer is correct either. You seem to be basing your answer just on the example provided and not on the description of the problem: "I want to go through each of the elements (A-F) **but for each element of only the first array (A-C).**"

Comment: I'll just be using `i < result[0].length` in the second iteration and not saving the new array on top of previous one

Comment: @laggingreflex Thanks :) I edited my answer to include that :)

Answer (score 1):

@thefourtheye's solution is very clever, but I think it's missing a main requirement of your question. Here's how you can fix it:

```
// Reduce all the arrays into a single array
var firstArray = result[0],
    allItems = result.reduce(function(result, current) {
        return result.concat(current);
    }, []), i, j;

// Iterate till the end of the array
for (i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i += 1) {
    // Start from the current i and iterate till the end
    for(j = i; j < allItems.length; j += 1) {
        console.log(firstArray[i].name + allItems[j].name);
    }
}
```